# Android TextView should scroll vertically automatically

Tags: java, android, xml, textview

I need a TextView which scrolls automatically vertically. This is my layout code:

**activity_info.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/iView"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/info"
        android:src="@mipmap/infoImage" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tView"
        android:layout_below="@+id/iView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:maxLines="500"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_below="@+id/tView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:gravity="center">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonYes"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:text="YES" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonNo"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@id/buttonYes"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"            
            android:text="NO" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

---

I read that I have to input this line:

```
tView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod())
```

into my onCreate method in my activity:

**InfoActivity.java**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_info);

    TextView tView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tView);
    tView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
}
```

If I do that, the TextView does not scroll automatically, if some new input (text) is inserted into the View. I know there are some other questions concerning the problem. But I've tried most of them.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: https://github.com/ayltai/Android-Lib-VerticalMarqueeTextView

Comment: Sorry, but I don't want such a TextView

Comment: Do you want the `TextView` to scroll indefinitely? Something similar to cast-scroll at the end of a feature film?

Comment: check this link it has perfect answer for vertical autoscrolling textview 
http://yuvarockers.blogspot.in/2017/04/vertical-autoscrolling-textview-in.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to set the textView to `android:gravity="bottom"`
and use `textView.append("\n"+"New Input Text.");` for new input text;

Answer (score 3):

You are almost there. Just add a few more things to achieve this,

First of all add those properties in your TextView

```
android:maxLines = "AN_INTEGER"
android:scrollbars = "vertical"
android:gravity="bottom"
```

Secondly as usual use,

```
tView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

This should solve your problem.

Comment: Yes it does scroll,but the scrolling is not smooth.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest wrapping your `TextView` in a `ScrollView`

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/sView"
    android:layout_below="@+id/iView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

  <TextView
      android:id="@+id/tView"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:maxLines="500"
      android:scrollbars="vertical"
      android:gravity="bottom" />

</ScrollView>
```

You can append new text by doing

```
public void appendAndScrollDown(String someText) {
    tView.append("\n" + someText);
    sView.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
}
```